# How to do special regex find and replace in emacs

Tags: python, regex, replace, emacs

If anyone can tell me how to do this in emacs, it would save me a TON of time: I want to do a find and replace, but save what I "find" to put in the "replace".

Basically, I have a bunch of print statements throughout my file.  I redefined print to verboseprint(), which prints when the verbose flag is present when my script is run.

However, since I'm using python 2.4, I was calling my print statements without parentheses:

```
print "Hello, world!"
```

I did a find and replace to get this:

```
verboseprint "Hello, world!"
```

But now, I want to do a find and replace to get this:

```
verboseprint ("Hello, world!")
```

This involves the following steps:

- Finding strings based on a regex (which I know emacs can do)
- Having the replacement string take a portion of the original string (which I'm not sure if emacs can do)

So in pseudocode, when I do my "find", I'd be searching for:

```
"verboseprint" + (characters until newline)
```

and I'd replace it with

```
"verboseprint(" + (characters until newline) + ")"
```

Is this even possible in emacs? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write a script to open the .py file and do the find and replaces that way?

Comment: Why not to use `2to3` program to fix print-statements and then rename calls from `print()` to `verboseprint()`?

Comment: Does it have to be in lisp really ? With `query-replace-regexp`, just search for `verboseprint \(.*\)` and replace with `verboseprint(\1)`. In the search form, the parenthesis (escaped by the slash) will capture a result that you can reuse with \1. See http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp and "start/end of group" then "string matched by the 1st group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick Emacs command that should do it.  Use `M-x foo` or bind `foo` to a key.

The regexp here assumes that the text after `verboseprint` and up to the line end is within double-quote characters. If not, or if you want to allow whitespace here or there, adjust the regexp accordingly.

```el
(defun foo (beg end)
  "Wrap argument to `verboseprint` in parens.
If the region is active and nonempty then do it throughout just the region.
Otherwise do it throughout the buffer."
  (interactive "r")
  (unless  (and transient-mark-mode  mark-active  (> end beg))
    (setq beg  (point-min)
          end  (point-max)))
  (unless (<= beg end) (setq beg (prog1 end (setq end beg))))
  (goto-char beg)
  (replace-regexp "verboseprint \"\\(.*\\)\"$"
                  "verboseprint (\"\\1\")"
                  nil beg end))
```

You can also do the same thing using just `C-M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`).  In that case, you don't double the backslashes.

Comment: `"."` is the same as `"[^\n]"`, and much easier for the interactive case. It sounds like there's only a single file, and this would be a one-off transformation, so I'd really be inclined to lead with the interactive solution.

Comment: @phils: Duh. Dunno what I was thinking. I guess I had in mind not including whitespace there but then dropped that. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

*Figured I'd go ahead and work on the assumption that you can edit the file, will edit when you answer my comment*

Not familiar with emacs (or too familiar with Python 2.5, to be honest), but assuming that you can access the file directly, this should work:

**MY TEST FILE**

```
VERBOSE=True

def verboseprint(*args,**kw):
    if VERBOSE:
        print *args, **kw

##Base case
verboseprint "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"

if VERBOSE: ## Testing for Indentation
    verboseprint "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

## Test kwargs    
verboseprint "Ut enim ad minim veniam,",end="\n\n"

## Test args
verboseprint "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea","commodo consequat."

## Test Single-line
if VERBOSE: verboseprint "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
```

**Script to do Replacements**

```
import re

FILE= ## Insert File Location
OUTPUT= ## Output File Location, different to be safe

REPLACERE=re.compile("verboseprint (?P<original>[^:]*)")
NEWPRINT="verboseprint( %s )\n"

def replacefunction(match):
    return NEWPRINT % match.group('original').rstrip()

f=open(FILE) ## I don't recall if context managers existed in Python 2.5
out=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    out.append(REPLACERE.sub(replacefunction,line))
f.close()

f=open(OUTPUT,'w')
f.write("".join(out))
f.close()
```

**MY OUT FILE**

```
VERBOSE=True

def verboseprint(*args,**kw):
    if VERBOSE:
        print *args, **kw

##Base case
verboseprint( "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," )

if VERBOSE: ## Testing for Indentation
    verboseprint( "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." )

## Test kwargs    
verboseprint( "Ut enim ad minim veniam,",end="\n\n" )

## Test args
verboseprint( "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea","commodo consequat." )

## Test Single-line
if VERBOSE: verboseprint( "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. " )
```